# How can i make the 'if' selection sturucture work for an array of inputs while doing a loop with a 'while' structure?

Tags: matlab

```
A=[21.04  93.3  133.5   158.5   182.5];   
k=0;
while k<=length(A)
    k=k+1;
    if A(k) <=170
        B=(4*10^-5).*(A).^2 + (0.0096).*A + 0.012;
    else
        B=(0.0005).*(A).^2 - (0.1503).*A + 14.131;
    end 
end
```

I was trying to use conditions to solve a problem with two outcomes, but Matlab kept telling me i cant use 'if' for an array selection. how can i improve it? please help me.

Comment: can you show the error you're getting

Comment: How did you try to "use 'if' for an array selection", and what exactly is the point of the while loop? (`B` seems to be overwritten in every iteration...)

Comment: `while k<=length(A)` is also a problem... should be `while k<length(A)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as it stands now, but there are a few issues I see. It seems like you are trying to make B dependent on the value of A. I don't think you are doing what you intend to do. A much simpler way would be:

```
B=zeros(size(A))
B(A<=170)=(4*10^-5).*(A(A<=170)).^2 + (0.0096).*A(A<=170) + 0.012)
B(A>170)=(0.0005).*(A(A>170)).^2 - (0.1503).*A(A>170) + 14.131;
```

Also, you are looping too much. A for loop would be much easier to follow, and useful in this case:

```
for k=1:length(A)
    if A(k) <=170
        B=(4*10^-5).*(A).^2 + (0.0096).*A + 0.012;
    else
        B=(0.0005).*(A).^2 - (0.1503).*A + 14.131;
    end 
end
```

Comment: the problem was, the script runs but the answer i got was wrong....as i was feeding the 'if' structure an 'array' not a 'scalar'.....i was confused but with the help i got from here it worked.........Thank You guys!!!!!!!